# How to override TextBox Text property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, properties

Can we override the `Text` property for `TextBox` control in such a manner that in every instance of text box in our project it replace `"'"` with `"''"` automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure, what exactly you goal is, but try to create custom control, ,by the instance of TextBox class and you can achieve...

Also, so you can create new properties for your control.
If you override existing property than it will behave as per your code, else it will be as it is...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below. You would have to change the id to whatever your textbox is, but basically everytime you change the text, this function will call and should replace all instances of a single quote with two single quotes.

My regex may not be entirely correct for javascript, can someone confirm this? The regex should check that no single quotes are next to each other. Otherwise it could have just been a simple replace with two quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#Textbox").change(function() {
          $("#Textbox").text($("#Textbox").text().replace(/(?<!')'(?!')/g, "''"));
       });
    });
```